# why the gray background push information to the right?

Tags: html, asp-classic

[image: example]

As you saw example image I posted, The gray box push the information to far right.
I don't want that. I want the information display right next to menu column on the left side. How can I get rid of gray background?

I also put example on JSFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/4efjh/

Here is HTML codes,

```
    <!-- #include file="../common.inc" -->
<!-- #include file="dbconn.inc" -->
<% response.buffer=true 
theUID = right(lcase(Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")),7)
'response.write vAdminRole
If Instr(Ucase(vAdminRole),Ucase("Admin")) = 0 Then
    oconn.Close
    set oconn = nothing
    Response.Redirect "../Denied.asp"
End if
%>

<!-- #include file="../Includes/send_mail.inc" -->
<!-- #include file="../Includes/dspfunctions.inc" -->
<!-- #include file="emails.inc" -->


<html>

<head>
<link REL="stylesheet" HREF="http://USMDLCDOWW002.intranet.dow.com/common/dow/includes/default.css" TYPE="text/css">
<link REL="stylesheet" HREF="http://USMDLCDOWW002.intranet.dow.com/common/dow/includes/hdr_n_nav.css" TYPE="text/css">

<STYLE TYPE='text/css'><!-- TD{font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt;} --->
    .style1
    {
        width: 61%;
    }
</STYLE>

<title>Dow NEA VM - Request Info</title>

</head>


<body onload="SetMenu()" >


<xml id="XmlUserInfo" src="http://USMDLCDOWW002.intranet.dow.com/common/components/userinfo/UserInfoXml.asp?UserID=me"> </xml>



<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td name="HeaderCell" id="HeaderCell" colspan="3"><a name="Top"></a><!--webbot bot="HTMLMarkup" ALT="&lt;h4&gt;The new Dow Header is in place ...&lt;/h4&gt;" TAG="XBOT" StartSpan -->
<IFRAME scrolling="no" width="100%" height="94" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" src="http://usmdlcdoww002.intranet.dow.com/common/dow/dowheader.htm"></IFRAME><!--webbot 
            BOT="HTMLMarkup" endspan i-checksum="29245" -->
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" style="border: 0" colspan="2">
    <!--webbot bot="Include" U-include="includes/site_header.htm" TAG="BODY" --></td>
    <td name="RightMarginCell" id="RightMarginCell" width="19%" rowspan="2"><img src="http://usmdlcdoww002.intranet.dow.com/common/images/rightspacer.gif" width="78" hspace="60" height="1"><p><!--webbot bot="PurpleText" PREVIEW="do not modify." --></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td name="MenuCell" id="MenuCell" valign="top" bgcolor="DDDDDD" style="border: 0">
    <!--webbot bot="Include" U-include="../../includes/menu.htm" TAG="BODY" --></td>



            <td class="style1" name="ContentCell" id="ContentCell" valign="top"><p class="PageHeader"><br>

            <p class="PageHeader" align="center">NEA Request Information </p>

            <p align="center"><b>ACCEPTED Request : </b><br><% = xAccept %></p>
            <form method="POST" action="ReqUpdate.asp?xReqID=<% = xReqID %>">

                <p align="center"><input type="submit" value="ACCEPT" name="reqACT"></p>
            </form>
            <p align="center">&nbsp;</p>

            <p align="center"><b>Actions</b></p>
            <form method="POST" name="sAction"  action="ReqUpdate.asp?xReqID=<% = xReqID %>&xUserID=<% = xUserID %>">
            <table border="1" width="100%" id="table6" class="TableSmall">
                <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" value="Completed"  onclick="Show(server)" onclick="Hide(addmsg)" name="reqAct">Request Complete</td>
                <td><input type="radio" value="Denied" onclick="Show(addmsg)" name="reqAct">Deny Request</td>
                <td><input type="radio" value="Deleted" onclick="Show(addmsg)" name="reqAct">Delete Guest</td>
                <td><input type="radio" value="Cancelled" onclick="Hide(addmsg)" name="reqAct">Close Req<p>
                    <select id="CanReason" name="CanReason" AddRec="-Select Note-" class="Smaller">
                    <option value="">-Select Note-</option> 
                    <option value="Duplicate">Duplicate</option>
                    <option value="MGMT override">MGMT override</option>
                    <option value="Out-of-Scope">Out-of-Scope</option>              
                    <option value="CLOSED">CLOSE</option>               
                    <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>                
                    </select>
                </td>

                </tr>
                <tr  class="noshow" id="addmsg" >
                    <td colspan="4" width="100%" >Enter additional message for denial/delete or leave blank.<br><textarea rows="2" cols="100%" name="sMSG"  ></textarea></td></tr>
                <tr  class="noshow" id="server" >
                    <td colspan="4" width="100%" >Enter Server Name.<br>
                    <input type="text" name="sServer" size="25%"></td>
                                        <td colspan="4" width="100%" >Comments.<br>
                    <input type="text" name="sComments" size="75%"></td>
                    </tr>

            </table>
                <p align="center">

            <p align="center">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1" onclick="javascript:return dovalidation()">


            <hr>
            </p>

            </form>

            <p><b>Req Info:</b><table border="1" width="100%" id="table7">
                <tr>
                    <td>Req ID :<% =strNUMit %><% = xReqID %></td>
                    <td>ReqDate :<% = xReqDate %></td>
            <% If instr(xStatus,"Canc") <> 0 then  %>
                    <td>Status :<% = xStatus & " Reason:[" & xCanReason & "]" %></td>
            <% Else %>
                    <td>Status :<% = xStatus %></td>
            <% End If %>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <p><b>User Info:</b><br>
            </p>
            <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="4" width="100%" border="1" id="table1">
                <tr>
                    <font size="2">
                    <td vAlign="top" colSpan="4"><b>Name:</b><br>
                    &nbsp;<% = xName %></td>
                    <td vAlign="top" colSpan="4"><b>User ID:</b><br>
                    &nbsp;<% = xUserID %> </td>
                    <td vAlign="top" colSpan="4"><b>Location:</b><br>
                    &nbsp;<% = xLocation & "<br>" & xRegion %> </td>
                    <td vAlign="top" colSpan="4"><b>Phone:</b><br>
                    &nbsp;<% = xPhone %> </td>
                    <td vAlign="top" colSpan="4"><b>Department:</b><br>
                    &nbsp;<% = xDepartment %> 
                    </td>
                    </font>
                </tr>
            </table>

                    <b><center><font size="2">***Request Info***</font></center>
    <table border='1'  cellspacing='0' width='100%'>


<%  If xCPU <> 0 then %>
    <tr><td valign='top' ><b>Project:</b> &nbsp; <% = xProject%> &nbsp;&nbsp;Owner:</b> &nbsp; <% = xOwner%></td>
    <td valign='top' ><b>Memory Size:</b> &nbsp; <% = xMemSize%> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>C Drive:</b> &nbsp; <% = xCSize%> </td></tr>
    <tr><td valign='top' ><b>Operating System:</b> &nbsp; <% = xOS %></td><td><b>D Drive:</b>  &nbsp; <% = xDSize%> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>E Drive:</b> &nbsp; <% = xESize%></td></tr>
    <tr><td valign='top' ><b>CPU:</b> &nbsp; <% = xCPU %> X 3.002GHz</td><td><b>Image Type:</b> &nbsp; <% = xType %></td></tr>
    <tr><td valign='top' ><b>DB:</b> &nbsp; <% = xDBtype %> Database</td><td><b></b> &nbsp;</td></tr>
    </table>

    <table border='1' cellpadding='4'  cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
    <tr><td valign='top' ><b>Sec OU</b> &nbsp;<br> <%= xSecOU %></td>
        <td valign='top' ><b>DR Approved</b> &nbsp; <%= xDRApproved %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>DR BIA #</b> &nbsp; <%= xDRBIA %></td></tr>
<%  Else %>
    <tr><td valign='top' ><b>Project:</b> &nbsp; <% = xProject%></td><td><b>Owner:</b> &nbsp; <% = xOwner%></td>
    <tr><td valign='top' ><b>Server Name:</b> &nbsp; <% = xServerName %></td><td><b>Req Type:</b> &nbsp; <% = xType %></td></tr>
    </table>


    <table border='1' cellpadding='4'  cellspacing='0' width='100%'>

<%  End If %>

    <tr><td valign='top' ><b>Additional Information</b> &nbsp;<br> 
    <%
    If inStr(xADDInfo,vbcrlf) <> 0 then
        xnaddinfo = Replace(xAddInfo,vbcrlf,"<br>")
    Else
        xnaddinfo = xAddInfo
    End If
    %>
    <% = xnaddinfo %>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td valign='top' ><b>Comments</b> &nbsp;<br> <%= xComments %></td>
<% if xServerName <> "" then %>
    <tr><td valign='top' ><b>Server name assigned :</b> &nbsp; <%= xServerName %></td>
<% End If %> 

    </table>




            &nbsp;<hr>
<%  If xCPU <> 0 then %>
            <p align="center"><font size="3">Process Flow</font></p>
        <form name="frmSort" action="ReqInfo.asp?xReqID=<%= xReqID  %>&pMON=<%= blnMON  %>&pBKP=<%= blnBKP  %>" method="post" >
            <table border="1" width="100%" id="table9">
                <tr>
                    <td><font size="3">Backups <br> <% = xBKP %></font></td>
                    <td align="center">
                    <b><font size="3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="BKP" <% = xBKPState %> value=True ></font></td>

                    <td align="center">
                        <p><font size="3">
                        <input type="Submit" value="Update" name="PUpdate"></font></p>

                    </td>

                    <td><font size="3">Monitoring <br> <% = xMonitor %></font></td>
                    <td align="center">
                    <b><font size="3">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Monitor" <% = xMONState %> value=True></font></td>

                </tr>
            </table>
                    </form>
<%  End If %>
            <b>
          <tr>

            <td name="Footer" id="Footer">
            <!--webbot bot="Include" U-include="../../NEAVM/Includes/footer.htm"
            TAG="BODY" --></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td name="SpacerCell" id="SpacerCell"><img src="http://USMDLCDOWW002.intranet.dow.com/common/images/topspacer.gif"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML as output not the ASP. There are 2 style sheets referenced. One of those could be causing the problem. Break the problem down into smaller pieces. Can you provide a small example on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I edit my post by adding a jsfiddle link. You can see the gray box on the left and that is what it should get rid of.

Comment: I changed the tag since this is ASP classic

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this inline style:

```
.style1
    {
        width: 61%;
    }
```

Adjust this to something like `10%` to see if this makes a difference, I can't test currently.

Comment: Nothing happen. Same Result. Have you check the JSFiddle? From what Jon P mentions, it probably from one of 2 REF css style. I posted on JSFiddle.